# Javascript split a large number into prime numbers array

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, numbers

I've a strange question, what is the best way javascript, starting from a Large number

```
var LargeNumber = 5234223;
```

To split into a array

```
var SingleNumberArray = [];
```

But with some limit:

1. I don't want that any number in array is more that X
2. I don't want to use soo many times the same number, for that reason
   I don't want to push the MaxValueInArray soo many times

   var MaxValueInArray = 43;

In order that the sum of all array is the LargeNumber?

At first glance I think that this can be useful use the prime number, but maybe this is a limit. So maybe the better way is to create a random function from 1 to MaxValueArray that every loop generate a number and before push them into array check if the sum is the starting number, if not push the number and restart, till the sum of the array is the same that the starting number, but at this point I think is better to check how much remain to have the right match. So if remain less that the MaxValueInArray I can push directly the value that remain.

The problem is that I don't know how to write down this function.

Btw, do you have a better idea to do that?

Comment: Why don´t you push your MaxValueInArray until the remainder is less than  MaxValueInArray and push the remainder?

Comment: Just because I don't want to have all the same numbers into it, maybe I don't have tell that :D

Comment: Well, then the idea is the same but pushing a random number between 1 and MaxValueInArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful, this can be intensive on a computational plan.

Each number is random between 0 and the number you set

```js
var LargeNumber = 5234223;
var MaxValueInArray = 43;
var MinValueInArray = 1;
var SingleNumberArray = [];


while (LargeNumber !== 0) {
  let n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (MaxValueInArray - MinValueInArray + 1)) + MinValueInArray;
  if (LargeNumber -n < 0) continue;
  LargeNumber -= n;
  SingleNumberArray.push(n);
}

console.log(5234223 === SingleNumberArray.reduce((i, j) => i + j))
console.log(SingleNumberArray);
```

Comment: Tnx, there's any chance to have the random number start from 1 or from a defined var?